# how to get span selected portion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, highlight, selection-api

is there a way to get the highlighted  selectionstart and selectedlenght on a span ?

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us *exactly* what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my own optimization of the algorithms in [IERange](http://code.google.com/p/ierange/), which provides a wrapper around IE's TextRange (which is what you get from the selection in IE) to give them the same interface as DOM Ranges.

To get the selection in the document, use something like the following:

```
var sel = window.getSelection(); // Provided by IERange in IE, built-in in other browsers
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0); // Note this doesn't work in Safari 2
```

`range` now has properties `startContainer` and `startOffset`, which are respectively a reference to a node and an offset within that node that represent the start of the selection, and corresponding properties `endContainer` and `endOffset` that represent the end of the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try on this:

```
  var span = document.getElementById('span1');
  if (document.selection) { //IE
      var bm = document.selection.createRange().getBookmark();
      var sel = span.createTextRange();
      sel.moveToBookmark(bm);

      var sleft = span.createTextRange();
      sleft.collapse(true);
      sleft.setEndPoint("EndToStart", sel);
      span.selectionStart = sleft.text.length
      span.selectionEnd = sleft.text.length + sel.text.length;
      span.selectedText = sel.text;
  }
  else if (span.selectionStart){ //FF
     span.selectedText = span.substring(span.selectionStart,span.selectionEnd);
  }

  alert("Selection Start==> " + span.selectionStart + "\n" +
     "Selection End  ==> " + span.selectionEnd + "\n" +
     "Selected Text  ==> " + span.selectedText + "\n" +
     "TextArea Value ==> " + span.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, but span.createTextRange(); gives an error. it only supports for textarea

Answer (score 0):

You might find some answers in this [quirksmode post](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html):

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your quick response. 

Problem here is that when a user select a text fragment on a particular span (asp.net label), i need to get the selected start and end? is there anyway that i could do this ?