# Getting `selectionStart` from a span's innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, selection-api

I have a roll your own text editor  that lets you change portions of a `textarea` element.  i want to adapt it to work with a span element.  I have no particular attachment to span.  The goal is simply to let someone edit html rather than a textarea.  I have it working fine in IE but am encountering some problems with Mozilla.

Since I'm using a span instead of form input I am using `innerHTML` instead of value.  However, I can't seem to get the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` functions to work on `innerHTML` as opposed to `value`.

Here is the `textarea` code that works fine....

html

```
<textarea id="textarea>Some text goes here</textarea><a href="javascript:void() onclick="editText">edit</a>
```

JS

```
function editText() {
    var len = displaytext.value.length; 
    var start = displaytext.selectionStart; 
    var end = displaytext.selectionEnd; 
    var sel = displaytext.value.substring(start, end); returns selection ok
    alert(sel);
}
```

However, the following adaption is not limiting the selection to start and end.

html

```
<span id="textarea>Some text goes here</span><a href="javascript:void() onclick="editText">edit</a>
```

JS

```
function editText() {
    var len = displaytext.innerHTML.length; //works ok
    var start = displaytext.selectionStart; //does not seem to work
    var end = displaytext.selectionEnd; //does not seem to work
    var sel = displaytext.innerHTML.substring(start, end); //returns whole innerHTML not selection
    alert(sel);
}
```

Is there a problem with `selecionStart` on `innerHTML`?  Workaround? Syntax error? Thanks for any suggesions.

Comment: What does `innerHTML` and `value` result in?  Could you get those in an alert, and paste the result here?  (or a link)

Comment: It returns undefined.   think i have discovered that selectionStart only works with textarea and text elements.  Looks like I need alternative to selectionStart and selectionEnd that works for spans...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get span selected portion using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605565/how-to-get-span-selected-portion-using-javascript)  Take a look here (the first answer explains it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don't use `innerHTML` for this kind of things. `textContent` is the way to go here.

I'm assuming a standard-compliant browser or IE9+ here.

The first thing to do is to get the document selection. You can do this by

```
var sel = getSelection();
```

Now, the selection can be empty, or can be outside the element, so check:

```
var rng, startSel, endSel, sel;
if (!sel.rangeCount
        || displaytext.compareDocumentPosition((rng = sel.getRangeAt(0)).startContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING
        || displaytext.compareDocumentPosition(rng.endContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING)
    sel = "";
else {
    ...
```

At this point, `rng` contains a `Range` object, with the properties `startOffset` and `endOffset`. This values are integers that refers to the position of the `textContent` property of `startContainer` and `endContainer` respectively.

You have a fairly simple case, which is a `<span>` element with a single text node. In this case, `rng.startContainer` and `rng.endContainer` will always be either `displaytext`, or some preceding or following element, but not a descendant of `displaytext`.

```
    ...
else {
    startSel = displaytext.compareDocumentPosition(rng.startContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING ? 0 : rng.startOffset;
    endSel = displaytext.compareDocumentPosition(rng.endContainer) === Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING ? displaytext.textContent.length : rng.endOffset;
    sel = displaytext.textContent.substring(startSel, endSel);
}
```

In case of a more complex structure of `displaytext`, with children elements and all, things become a little tricky. You'd have to find the text offset of the starting node in the descendants tree of `displaytext`, and the best way to do so is using a `TreeWalker` object walking the text nodes:

```
var tw = document.createTreeWalker(displaytext, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, null);
```

Comment: Hi, textContent works nicely, however, am no getting whole script to work...  http://jsfiddle.net/u9Re7/2/  Am I missing something?  Many thanks.

Comment: @user1904273 Yeah, sorry, there was an extra parenthesis in the first `if` statement. Fixed [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9Re7/3/) for you.

Comment: never mind.  got it to work.  There was an extra close parentheses after Preceding.  Thanks again!